# django field using pictures instead of text

Tags: django

If I choose one of  whose input value is radio in HTML and submit, the selected one is delivered to the models, and finally, I want to retrieve the selected image from HTML again.
But I can't even get a clue. What should I do?
And I also wonder how to connect and use these with forms.py and html.
I want to know the exact answer because the image field is set as a temporary measure.

models.py
'''

```
class Guest(models.Model):
author = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=20)
content=models.TextField()
created_at =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
sticker=models.ImageField(label="Decorate the picture next to it!",widget=models.RadioSelect(choices=STICKER_CHOICES))

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.author},{self.content}'
```

'''

main html

```
Sticker: 
                    <div class="table">
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/boat.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/airplane.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/bird.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table">
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/board.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/fish.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/starfish.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table">
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/turtle.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/shell.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                       <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/palm.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;"></input>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML radio input elements are self closing, so either `<input>` or `<input />` without children elements. Your HTML sample has the image element as a child (inside the opening and closing tag) of input which means the `<img>` is not associated with the radio input.

Instead you need to add a value attribute to the input that is passed to your python backend.

Here's a sample of how your HTML should look

```
                <div class="table">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="boat"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/boat.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="airplane"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/airplane.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="bird"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/bird.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                </div>
                <div class="table">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="board"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/board.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="fish"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/fish.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="starfish"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/starfish.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                </div>
                <div class="table">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="turtle"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/turtle.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="shell"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/shell.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                   <input type = "radio" name = "major" style="margin-left:15px;" value="palm"><img src="{% static 'diary/css/images/sticker/palm.png' %}" style="height:80px;width:80px;">
                </div>
```